# hint in TextField doesn't display

Tags: nativescript-vue

I am working with Nativescript-Vue and have several text fields that I would like to put a little text in the background so the user knows what values (name, address, etc) should go in there.  I don't have room for labels and I see that TextField has a hint...so my thinking is I should be able to use that? However, this doesn't render anything.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="*" class="box">
    <TextField class="line-text" v-model="customer.firstName"  hint="First Name" width="500px" marginBottom="2px" marginTop="2px"></TextField>
    <TextField class="line-text" v-model="customer.lastName" hint="Last Name" width="500px" marginBottom="2px" marginTop="2px"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Here a playground with your example: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=r53WCd It works, just tested. What did you do that it didn't work?

Comment: That code is virtually identical to mine.  I think the difference might be the page loads.  I have a beforeMount() but it doesn't touch this value.

Comment: Can you share a playground example with your exact code?